For any open set $U\subset X$, $X$ an integral scheme, $p\in U$, $\mathscr O_{X}(U)\rightarrow \mathscr O_{X,p}$ is injective
In the case that $U$ is affine, the statement is trivial because the stalk at $p$ is the localization of $\mathscr O_{X}(U)$ except for elements in prime ideal $p$ and the map identifies with the map $\varphi: \mathscr O_{X}(U)\rightarrow \mathscr O_{X,p} $. As the $X$ is integral, the ring $\mathscr O_{X}(U)$ is integral domain and hence has no zero divisor, which means the map is injective. But how to prove the case where $X$ is not necessarily affine? My idea and confusion is if I consider an open cover $U=\cup_i U_i$ and choose $f\in \mathscr O_X(U)$ such that $\varphi(f)=0$, then we need to show $f|_ { Ui} =0$ for all $U_i$. But it could happen that $p\not \in U_i$, then the map $\mathscr O_X(U_i)\rightarrow \mathscr O_{X,p} $ is not defined.

Let $X$ be an integral scheme and $U$ be an open subscheme of $X$. One can prove that $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is injective. Indeed, if $X = \bigcup_{i \in I}U_i$ is an open cover by affines and $f \in \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is a function, then $f_{\mid U}$ is determined by $f_{\mid U_i \cap U}$ for $i\in I$ according to sheaf condition. Thus $f_{\mid U} = 0$ if and only if $f_{\mid U_i\cap U} = 0$ for all $i$ if and only if $f_{\mid U_i} = 0$ for all $i$ if and only if $f = 0$
Now we proceed as follows. It suffices to prove that $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is injective. Pick an open affine $p\in U\subseteq X$. Then $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ factors as $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}(U)$ followed by $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$. Both these morphisms are injective. Hence the composition is injective.

Thank you a lot. Your answer is very helpful. I still have a tiny question. Why $f|_{U_i\cap U}=0$ will imply $f|{U_i}=0$. I think because $X$ is integral hence $\mathscr O_X(U_i)$ is integral domain and because  $U_i$ is affine $\Rightarrow \mathscr O_X(U_i\cap U) $ is localization of $\mathscr O_X(U_i) $ hence injective, right?

$\mathcal{O}_X(U\cap U_i)$ is not necessarily a ring of fractions of $\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$.

Function vanishes on $U\cap U_i$  if and only if its stalks vanish at each point of $U\cap U_i$. In particular, it vanishes at some point $q \in U\cap U_i$. On the other hand $\mathcal{O}{X}(U_i)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}{X,q}$ is injective as you observed in the statement.

Let $p \in U$ be non-affine. Then, we can find an affine neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $U$. Then $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{O}_{X, p}$ factors as the composition $$\mathcal{O}_X(U) \longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_X(V)\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X, p}$$ so it suffices to show that the restriction maps for $\mathcal{O}_X$ are injective. For this, if $\psi \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ satisfies $\psi|_V = 0$, then the vanishing locus $$Z_U(\varphi) = \{x \in U\;|\;\varphi_x \in \mathfrak{m}_x\}$$ is a closed subset of $U$ containing $V$. Since $U$ is reduced and irreducible, it follows that $\psi = 0$, as required.
